# Time series caching in Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm developing a rails website and trying to implement a cache layer.In current website we are displaying the stock information for each stock using D3 chart rendering and every other second sending a request to server for new data and appending it with the current rendered D3 chart.

**My Design approach***

I will implement a caching layer that will internally send request to database ,let say every 10 second and update the cache for last one hour so at given point my cache will always have last 1 hour of data so any request that match with in this time stamp will be served from cache.

Issues :

1. How to store data in cache. Currently,I'm thinking of memcached for distributed caching and key as timestamp but how I invalidate the earliest timestamp key when new key with latest 10 second data comes in ?
2. Some of the data don't come sequentially, let say data for 14:02:33 will come later than 14:02:38. How to avoid such scenarios

Let me know if you guys have better approach to design this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Memcached supports expiration natively. That means you can assign 1 hour expiration for every new key and they will be removed automatically by the Memcached.
2. Such problem does not exist as memcached doesn't care about the key sequences. It's a single key - single value system.
   If you care about different timeframe, you can quantize time by let's say 5s, so 14:02:33 -> 14:02:30; 14:02:37 -> 14:02:35, and so on.